# HighchartsReact download chart to PNG/SVG/IMG from js code

Tags: javascript, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm trying to use [Highcharts React](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react) to export the chart as any kind of image (jpg, png, svg..).

I've read, that Highcharts-React creates another instance for exporting. So there's no getSVG() function on the Highcharts Ref.

Is there any way to get the image via code?

```
const App = () => {
  const chartComponent = useRef(null);

  const printChartAsImage = () => {
    // chart to image
    const chart = chartComponent.current.chart;
    console.log(chart.getSVG());
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={printChartAsImage}>Print visible page</button>
      <div id="element-to-print">
        <HighchartsReact
          highcharts={Highcharts}
          options={chartOptions}
          ref={chartComponent}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: [https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server)

[https://github.com/highcharts/export-csv](https://github.com/highcharts/export-csv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the Highcharts `exporting` module:

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import exportingModule from "highcharts/modules/exporting";

exportingModule(Highcharts);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-fork-cmmwwg?file=/demo.jsx

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview

Comment: exportingModule(Highcharts);   should this be invoked once for entire App ?

Comment: Also it would be helpfull if you can explain how to do offline exporting

Comment: Hi @Dattatreya Kugve, Yes, it should be invoked only once. To add offline exporting use: `import offlineExporting from "highcharts/modules/offline-exporting"; offlineExporting(Highcharts);`